# Set Focus to a popup window from C# (or JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I'm trying to get a popup window to focus i tried the `window.open().focus();`
but it keeps changing in the background so I'm trying in my code to close a window and re-opening it again.

```
string url = "Report.aspx";
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window456789123', 'width=650,height=500,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')";

string t = "window.close()";
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", t, true);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

I tried it in Jquery but that didn't work either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
        window.focus();
    });
</script>
```

Flow:

1. Main page: click button1 ► opens popup1
2. popup is in focus and shows data
3. mainpage(gets focus): click button2 ► opens same popup1
4. popup changes data (but dos not get focus) **This is the issue**

Comment: Yes the window.focus() focuses on the actual browser window. Opening the window should focus it. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp shouldn't it?

Comment: @RichardHousham nope sorry it dos not work it stays on the background

Comment: @RichardHousham i updated the original post

Comment: can you please provide different window name when you are opening window using button2. Looks like because of same window name this issue is happening.

Comment: @alok_dida this is exactly what i have now.
So you are telling me its not possible to set focus if you use the same popup window?

Comment: If both window are opened, then yes. it will get confuse.

Comment: @alok_dida, with "both window" do you mean the mainpage and the popup1 window or do you think that there are 2 different popup windows? (There is only 1 popup window used for different rendering)

Comment: Ok I've done a fiddle which shows what you should have. https://jsfiddle.net/x2y10egu/ If I click off one window and click on another then it comes back (reloads) and gets focus. If you are expecting something like a text box getting focus or something in the loaded window then you need to have something within the page that is getting loaded to give that text box focus.

Comment: @RichardHousham tks for the answer. Its working in a lose project, but not in my main project. Maby something is blocking it. If you want you can post your comment as a answer. I will accept it!

Comment: @Belguimclub thanks, just done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've done a fiddle which shows what you should have. [View Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2y10egu)

If I click off one window and click on another then it comes back (reloads) and gets focus.

If you are expecting something like a text box getting focus or something in the loaded window then you need to have something within the page that is getting loaded to give that text box focus.

```
      <script> function openwin(url) {
      window.open(url, 'popup_window456789123','width=650,height=500,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes ')
    }
</script>

    <button onclick="openwin('https://www.webpagetest.org/')">
Button1
</button>
<button onclick="openwin('https://www.webpagetest.org/')">
Button2
</button>
```